# Multiple captures on same text with regexp_matches() using different regex patterns

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, regex-lookarounds

Given the following title `Olympic National Park, WA. [OC][5239x3492]` the goal is to capture tags `OC`, `5239x3492`, and also capture `5239` and `3492` as two separate captures. Thought was to use a series of positive look aheads `(?=)` to non-consumingly make `N` matches, like `[\[\(\{](?=[a-zA-Z0-9\-_ \/]+)(?=[0-9]+)[\}\)\]]`, however this just lead to a bunch of empty strings (and confusion). Seem to have a misunderstanding of how regexp_matches or positive look aheads work, assist greatly appreciated.

Statement:

```
SELECT (
  regexp_matches(
    'Olympic National Park, WA. [OC][5239x3492]', 
    '[\[\(\{]([a-zA-Z0-9\-_ \/]+)[\}\)\]]', 
    'gi'
  )
);
```

Current output:

```
 regexp_matches 
----------------
 {OC}
 {5239x3492}
(2 rows)
```

Desired output:

```
 regexp_matches 
----------------
 {OC}
 {5239x3492}
 {5239}
 {3492}
(4 rows)
```

Comment: There is always 2 values and values separated by `x`  for tags like `[5239x3492]` ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze If some captures are missing because of being abnormally formed then this is okay. People type all kinds of arbitrary stuff like `[5k - 5239x3492]` or `[5k/5239x3492]`, ideally would capture and split into separate tags as appropriate, although not necessary at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matches cannot overlap in any regular expression implementation. What you can do however, is to split the matches like `5239x3492` afterwards:

```
select     u
from       t
cross join regexp_matches(col, '[\[\(\{]([a-z0-9 \/_-]+)[\}\)\]]', 'gi') m
left join  regexp_matches(m[1], '(\d+)x(\d+)', 'gi') s on true
cross join unnest(m || s) u
```

http://rextester.com/VKDTON30263

Comment: Are you sure matches cannot overlap in any regular expression implementation? There was a comment on the original question, that bizarrely has since been deleted, that used one regex_matches to pull out multiple forms. No idea why the fellow deleted the comment. Anywho, this works too, thanks!

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson I'm pretty sure. You can (in some implementation) workaround that with look-behind & look-ahead, but those are not considered to be *part* of the actual match. So, to *extract* some characters multiple times with a single expression is not possible.